# Account name must be unique

Tags: salesforce

What I am looking to do is Make it the "Account" name field require a unique name.

Basically If one of my reps tries to create an account, and that account all ready exists it tells them no that account all ready exists.

Salesforce tells me this funicality is not build into sales force. Any help or dirrection would we wonderfull.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new text field, call it `Name__c`. Mark it as unique, length... probably 80, same as `Name` field length.

Create new [Workflow rule](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_wfrules.htm&siteLang=en_US) with condition `ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Name) || ISBLANK(Name__c)` and the action should be a field update that simply has `Name` in the formula that determines new value.

Remember to activate the workflow and to fill in the newly created field because it will be blank for all your existing accounts!

Your call if you want to show the field on page layouts (it's quite "technical" so could be hidden). If you do - it's a good idea to make it readonly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this validation:

```
AND(CONTAINS(VLOOKUP( $ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name , $ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name, Name), Name), OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Name)) )
```

Comment: Can you try to expand on this or explain your answer at all?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce offers duplication management for this purpose.

You just set up Matching Rules and Duplicate Rules for your Account object in Setup > Administration Setup > Data.com Administration > Duplicate Management.

Link: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You could write a trigger to prevent duplicates. It'd be a "before insert" trigger that queried for existing accounts with the same name. If an Account name already exists, you'd call `addError()` on the new Account record, preventing the insert from continuing.

Have you searched the AppExchange for solutions? Might want to check out something like [DupeCatcher](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLlEAO)

Comment: If you can stay 100% trigger-free, then yeah. Mixing triggers and workflow can result in a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a custom field to contain the account name (something like "Business Name") and then ensure that's required and unique.

You'd need to do some basic Data Loader gymnastics to move your account names to the new field, and come up with a strategy for populating the existing Name field for accounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND(VLOOKUP($ObjectType.Object_Name.Fields.Name, $ObjectType.Object_Name.Fields.Name, Name) = Name, OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Name)))
```